# java, counting Standard Deviation. stuck in my last code

Tags: java

```
public int deviasi(){
    //sum
    int jumlah=0;
    for (int i=0; i<banyak; i++){
        jumlah = jumlah+nilai[i];
    }
    //mean
    int rata2;
    rata2=jumlah/banyak;

    //menghitung deviasi
    double deviasi = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<banyak;i++){
     deviasi += Math.pow(nilai[i] - rata2,2);
    }
    return

    Math.sqrt (deviasi/banyak);

}
```

i got error in my last code. it told me the problem because of different data type between deviasi and banyak. but, i've changed the data type to make them have the same data type. but the error warning still told me the problem because of different data type between deviasi and banyak. i got stuck. T_T

Comment: Where is the declaration of `banyak`?

Comment: Math.sqrt (deviasi/(double)banyak);

Comment: It Is a Bad idea to give a method and a variable the same name

Comment: What is "an error"?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer this if you name your variables in English.

Comment: It looks to me like all variables except i should have type double.

Comment: sory, i just share a part of my code.

Comment: but it's working now. i just change my method's data type to double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in comments you need to work with double as variable type

```
public class StandDev {

  public double standardDevioation(int[] numbers){
    int count = numbers.length;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      sum += numbers[i];
    }

    double mean = sum / count;

    double sumDiff = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i< count; i++){
      sumDiff += Math.pow(numbers[i] - mean,2);
    }

    return Math.sqrt (sumDiff/count);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers =  {-5, 1, 8, 7, 2};
    StandDev standDev = new StandDev();
    System.out.println(standDev.standardDevioation(numbers));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Code returns 3.7549966711037173
public class Devs {

```
public static double deviasi(){

    //sum
    int jumlah= 0;
    int[] nilai = {4,7,6,3,9,12,11,12,12,15};
    int banyak = 10;


    for (int i=0; i<banyak; i++){
        jumlah += nilai[i];
    }

    //mean
    int rata2;
    rata2=jumlah/banyak;

    //menghitung deviasi
    double deviasi = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<banyak;i++){
     deviasi += Math.pow(nilai[i] - rata2,2);
    }

    return Math.sqrt (deviasi/banyak);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {


    System.out.println(deviasi());

}
```

}

Comment: Thank you.. i just change my method's data type. and it running well.

Comment: but, can i print value of deviasi in deviasi method. so, in main method i just need to call deviasi's method(deviasi()), not writing this code System.out.println(deviasi());

Comment: i'm sorry for basic question i ask, im still newbie in programing.